# Identify systemd/sysctl conf files, that are not distribution-native

Tags: linux, unix, google-cloud-platform, sysctl

I have an GCP provided Unix/Linux (RHEL7 and CentOS7 in this case, at the time of writing this SO question) files, for example:

`/etc/sysctl.d/60-gce-network-security.conf`

The check can be done by simply grepping/catting/sedding , but it will be hardcoded, unmantainable and simply stupid.

Therefore, is there a way to actually scan the files and try to guess if they are native to distribution or not?

My idea is to scan all files, used by sysctl / systemd unit files, but I want to have more input before implementing the logic, if that is really a viable solution by industry professionals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-step procedure for this but you can guess based on the information the package manager provides for each file you are interested in.

For the RPM-based distributions like CenOS you can use `rpm -qf` and `rpm -qif`.

Also, you may find some input from the tools and customization files Google uses to prepare GCE images:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/blob/master/daisy_workflows/image_build/enterprise_linux/kickstart/el7-post.cfg